# How does the Enterprise Library's CryptographyManager.CompareHash method work?

Tags: hash, enterprise-library

I've been wondering how the CryptographyManager is able to compare a salted hash with the plain text. It has to save the salt for each hash somewhere, right? Has anyone any insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I checked out the source code and it is actually quite trivial: The salt is prepended to the actual hash value. When the hash is compared to a plaintext the salt is extracted and used to hash the plaintext. These two hash values (= salt + hash) are then compared.

Answer (score 1):

We ship [source code](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=bcb166f7-dd16-448b-a152-9845760d9b4c&displaylang=en). Take a look at CryptographyManagerImpl.cs in the Cryptography solution.
Also, you may want to review our unit tests - the ones that start with HashProvider should give you additional insight.